# Dynamic dropdownlists in django using javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, python, html, django

I am trying to populate a dropdownlist with the result of the execution of an .exe program. The .exe will return a concatenation of items, separated by special characters. This will in turn be captured by the corresponding view at views.py, and rendered to the .html. In this .html, there is javascript code that runs on window load, splits the rendered string using the special characters and (theorically) populates the dropdownlist.

Part of my code is as follows:

the c++ code (will be compiled into the .exe)

```
   while(i<MAX_ITEMS)    
        std::cout << i << "$" << item[i] << "&";
```

views.py (inside of the view that the url is calling)

```
os.chdir(r'C:/directory')
proc = subprocess.Popen([r'C:/directory/Application.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
y = proc.stdout.read()
proc.wait()
return render_to_response('home.html', {'list': y})
```

finally, the html file containing the javascript function

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
        <title></title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
            window.onload = function Func() {               
                var lists = document.getElementById('list'); 
                var liststxt = new Array();
                liststxt[1] = "{{ list }}";
                var items = liststxt[1].split("&"); 
                for (var count = lists.options.length-1; count >-1; count--){ 
                    lists.options[count] = null; 
                } 
                for (i=0; items.length; i++){ 
                    var values = items[i].split("$"); 
                    var option = new Option(values[1], values[2], false, false);  
                    lists.options[lists.length] = option; 
                }                          
            } 
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body>  
        <form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
            <select name="list" id="list"> 
                <option>--</option> 
            </select>                 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

I think I have tried almost all intermediate possibilities, and they work perfect (hardcoding a string instate of reciveing it from the exe, rendering the result of the .exe directly at the html instate of processing it using javascript, etc.), but if I put everything together, it fails to populate the dropdownlist...

I am doing this code in order to have several dependant dropdownlists, and I am doing it following the proof of concept seen [here](http://www.nerdydork.com/dynamic-filtered-drop-down-choice-fields-with-django.html). I am not using Ajax (or Dajax, or Dajaxice), because I couldn't manage to install it properly after trying many times.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't need to "install" Ajax: it's a technique, not a library. But can you provide an example of the output of your exe file?

Comment: The exe outputs something like that: 

`1$First Item&2$Second Item&3$Third Item...`

This information is recived at the views, as I can display it in the screen using HttpResponse. It is also reaching the html, as I can render it to the html and display it. But I fail using it at the javascript function. On the other hand, if I pass to the javascript function the same string I would get from the exe, but now I hardcode it at views.py, it works

Comment: Are you sure it is *exactly* the same? Is there any extra stuff before or after the value? What do you get if you put a print statement in the view, eg `print "Output: " + y + "..."`?

Comment: yes, I can't see any difference...

Comment: if I take what I get at "y" using print, I copy it and manually hard-code it at views, then the javascript works fine

Comment: OK, what does the rendered output of the Javascript look like, once the list has been inserted?

Comment: At the javascript code I try `document.write("{{ list }}");`. If what I am rendering is `y`, where `y = proc.stdout.read()`, then nothing happens. Else, if I render `w` (the hardcoded version of the resulting string of proc.stdout.read()) `w = "1$First Item&2$Second Item&3$Third Item..."`, then I see this properly rendered at the html.

Comment: sorry, at the end of `y` there might be a new line symbol I haddn't noticed until comparing both string using difflib

Comment: SOLVED! at the end of my c++ code, I did `std::cout << result << std::endl;`. Eventhough `result=""`, it was printing `endl`. Now it works like a charm, and populates correctly the dropdownlist. Many thanks Daniel :)